# Can I respec my character in Dragon's Crown?

Tags: dragons-crown

I'm up to about level 10 and so far have just been plopping points into skills almost at random, to try them out. Am I going to regret not saving these points for higher-level skills, or is there a way to respec my character? So far the game sort of seems to unlock new things as I go (like the mage tower, and eventually rune magic) so I wonder if respeccing will be unlocked at some point too.

I figure it's better to find out sooner rather than later, so I can restart my guy if it turns out respeccing isn't an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to reset your skill points for a character. There's a post-game dungeon called the "Labyrinth of Chaos" that eventually becomes unlocked. It's divided into multiple floors, which clearing them rewards you with special items based on your class. Unspoken of, it also provides you with an item called "Amnesia Elixir" on every third floor clear (for the first three times you do this, that is). This sits in your Armory's Item slots and is your means to reset skill points (so, by consequence, you can get 3 of these per character).

You use these in the Guild Hall. **Note that this will reset every skill you have *except* Deep Pockets**. You apparently can't get refunded on the extra inventory slots, whether or not you're using them, so these will be permanent investments. As such, pick wisely when you choose Deep Pockets.